# How to resolve conflict when CMS page URL and controller rewrite URL are the same?

Tags: url-rewrite, cms-block, router

I have a page named `stores` and I have a following rewrite:

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <designer_url>
            <from><![CDATA[#^/stores/#]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[/storescontroller/index/index/location/]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </designer_url>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```

So the idea is for `http://mystore.com/stores` to go to the cms page and for `http://mystore.com/store/dallas/` to go to the controller. How can I resolve this conflict?

THanks in advance

Comment: Unless you are using a thoroughly ancient version of Magento you should not be using global rewrites.

Answer (score 2):

You have three decent options besides the global rewrite you noted (it's very, very deprecated).

Possibly the easiest option is via webserver configuration (e.g. `RewriteRule` for Apache).

Another option would be to add a new router class with a `match()` method which recognizes your URL structure and can rewrite the request object just as the CMS router (`Mage_Cms_Controller_Router`) does:

```
public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)
{
    //snip...

    $request->setModuleName('cms')
        ->setControllerName('page')
        ->setActionName('view')
        ->setParam('page_id', $pageId);
    $request->setAlias(
        Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
        $identifier
    );

    return true;
}
```

Because the request is not marked as dispatched the router loop in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front::dispatch()` will re-cycle and then the Standard router will match the new request structure.

Speaking of `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front::dispatch()` - in more recent versions of Magento it is also possible through configuration to inject your own rewrite class:

```
public function dispatch()
{
    //snip...
    $this->_getRequestRewriteController()->rewrite();
    //snip...
}
```

`$this->_getRequestRewriteController()` reads the value at `global/request_rewrite/model`, which you can overwrite with your own value. You can extend the `Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite_Request` class and override the `rewrite()` method, or you can implement your own class with a `rewrite()` method which detects the URL param/structure you want to use and defers to the core class.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a rewrite for this? Your cms page should work if the URL listed in admin is "stores". Then within your module config.xml you can use the routers tag and assign a frontname as:

```
<routers>
   <frequent>
      <use>standard</use>
      <args>
        <module>xxx_xxx</module>
        <frontName>store</frontName>
      </args>
   </frequent>
</routers>
```

From this you could have a dallasAction in your controller which loads the desired content.

Comment: Obviously I need something different. 1. CMS page name and router frontName in your example need to be the same: both "stores" (this is why I emphasized that it is a conflict). 2. I need a rewrite, because I don't want to write an action for every single location - this is why I do rewrite, and pass "dallas" as parameter to controller index.

Answer (score 1):

Instead using `global rewrite`, you can create the `URL Rewrite` in admin panel.

Navigate to

> admin > catalog > Url Rewrite Management > Add Url Rewrite

Select the `Custom` for Url Rewrite.

```
Id path >> Unique id 

Requested Path >> store/dallas/

Target Path  >> /storescontroller/index/index/location/
```

Now

`http://mystore.com/stores` will goto your cms page

`http://mystore.com/stores/dallas` will goto the controller

Refer [**this**](http://blog.beetleweb.com/2012/10/creating-custom-magento-url-rewrites/)